# Angularjs javascript canvas not cleared

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html5-canvas

I have an application with a number of canvases within a page. These canvases get a value (picture) by inserting a Base64 string into an input element and clicking a button (that handles the required manipulations in the background).

My problem is that, even without loading any Base64 string, somehow the canvases retain the pictures that were loaded in a previous session.

I'm using Chrome right now. Tried closing Chrome and reopening, deleting history, etc. Still even when the page is open after cleaning history, the contents of the canvases still exist.

I also added the following code to the beginning of the relevant AngularJS controller:

```
Context_Picture.clearRect(0                    , 
                          0                    , 
                          Canvas_Picture.width ,
                          Canvas_Picture.height ) ;
```

which does not resolve the issue.

Any clue why am I experiencing this and how to hard-clear the canvases?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the error!!!! It is not that the original picture was being held somewhere, but it was picking a white rectangle when no picture was added (I saw a Base64 string and it didn't occur to me that it was of a white rectangle).

Fixed now and working as needed.